# Automatically generate mean-adjusted data for regression in R

Tags: r, function, regression, predict

I am running into a bit of a roadblock with programming a data generating function for regression predictions. The normally way one would do what I am trying to do (without automating it like I am seeking to), is to do the following:

```
#### Fit Data ####
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width,iris)

#### Create Test Data ####
newdata <- data.frame(
  Petal.Width = mean(iris$Petal.Width),
  Sepal.Width = seq(
    min(iris$Sepal.Width),
    max(iris$Sepal.Width),
    length.out = 100
  )
)

#### Generate Predictions ####
pred <- predict(fit,newdata=newdata)
pred
```

The idea is that you select one variable of interest and control the other values by setting them to their mean, then predict the data. This consequently gives you the following predicted values:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
4.133390 4.124783 4.116176 4.107569 4.098962 4.090355 4.081749 4.073142 
       9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
4.064535 4.055928 4.047321 4.038714 4.030107 4.021500 4.012893 4.004286 
      17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
3.995680 3.987073 3.978466 3.969859 3.961252 3.952645 3.944038 3.935431 
      25       26       27       28       29       30       31       32 
3.926824 3.918217 3.909611 3.901004 3.892397 3.883790 3.875183 3.866576 
      33       34       35       36       37       38       39       40 
3.857969 3.849362 3.840755 3.832148 3.823542 3.814935 3.806328 3.797721 
      41       42       43       44       45       46       47       48 
3.789114 3.780507 3.771900 3.763293 3.754686 3.746079 3.737473 3.728866 
      49       50       51       52       53       54       55       56 
3.720259 3.711652 3.703045 3.694438 3.685831 3.677224 3.668617 3.660010 
      57       58       59       60       61       62       63       64 
3.651404 3.642797 3.634190 3.625583 3.616976 3.608369 3.599762 3.591155 
      65       66       67       68       69       70       71       72 
3.582548 3.573941 3.565335 3.556728 3.548121 3.539514 3.530907 3.522300 
      73       74       75       76       77       78       79       80 
3.513693 3.505086 3.496479 3.487872 3.479266 3.470659 3.462052 3.453445 
      81       82       83       84       85       86       87       88 
3.444838 3.436231 3.427624 3.419017 3.410410 3.401803 3.393197 3.384590 
      89       90       91       92       93       94       95       96 
3.375983 3.367376 3.358769 3.350162 3.341555 3.332948 3.324341 3.315734 
      97       98       99      100 
3.307128 3.298521 3.289914 3.281307
```

However, I will probably have to do this over and over again and coding all of this by hand every time isn't going to be very efficient, so I am looking to automate it with a custom function.

##### Test Case

So far, this is what I have come up with to attempt automating the process, but it is obviously not helpful. The idea is for the function to take all but one of the variables as their mean, and afterwards select one variable as a sequenced number (from its min to its max) like what I have above. The generated data should also retain the names of the predictors plugged in (so they should say "test1" and so on when input into the function):

```
#### Create Test Data ####
test.data <- data.frame(
  test1 = rnorm(100),
  test2 = rnorm(100),
  test3 = rnorm(100),
  test4 = rnorm(100)
)

#### Make Function ####
gen.seq <- function(data,x1,x2,x3,x4){
  
  data <- data
  
  newdata <- data.frame(
    x1 = mean(data$x1, na.rm = T),
    x2 = mean(data$x2, na.rm = T),
    x3 = mean(data$x3, na.rm = T),
    x4 = seq(
      min(data$x4, na.rm = T),
      max(data$x4, na.rm = T),
      length.out = 100
    )
  )
}

#### Generate Mean Controlled Data ####
gen.seq(test.data,
        test1,
        test2,
        test3,
        test4)
```

I would also like it to include the `predict` function within this function if possible, but without accomplishing the data generation step first, it is futile to do at the moment. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general/agnostic answer which simply creates the dataframes

```
reps=3 # sequence length
cols=c("test1","test2","test4") # columns to vary
test.data.mean=as.data.frame.list(colMeans(test.data))

sapply(
  cols,
  function(x){
    y=names(test.data.mean)[names(test.data.mean)!=x]
    z=setNames(data.frame(seq(min(test.data[x]),max(test.data[x]),length.out=reps)),x)
    z[y]=test.data.mean[y]
    z[colnames(test.data.mean)]
  },
  simplify=F,
  USE.NAMES=T
)
```

resulting in

```
$test1
       test1       test2       test3       test4
1 -1.9394516 -0.03640007 -0.04115825 -0.07265569
2  0.1961531 -0.03640007 -0.04115825 -0.07265569
3  2.3317578 -0.03640007 -0.04115825 -0.07265569

$test2
        test1       test2       test3       test4
1 -0.05502075 -2.66943429 -0.04115825 -0.07265569
2 -0.05502075 -0.02634115 -0.04115825 -0.07265569
3 -0.05502075  2.61675199 -0.04115825 -0.07265569

$test4
        test1       test2       test3       test4
1 -0.05502075 -0.03640007 -0.04115825 -2.60890222
2 -0.05502075 -0.03640007 -0.04115825  0.01795227
3 -0.05502075 -0.03640007 -0.04115825  2.64480676
```

Comment: Took me a second to adjust this for my specific use case but it worked after some minor adjustments. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be achieved quite easily with the effects package

```
library(effects)
mod=lm(mpg~cyl+qsec+drat,data=mtcars)
allEffects(
  mod,
  xlevels=lapply(mtcars[,names(mod$coefficients[-1])],function(x){
    seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=10)
  })
)
```

resulting in

```
 model: mpg ~ cyl + qsec + drat

 cyl effect
cyl
               4 4.44444444444444 4.88888888888889 5.33333333333333 5.77777777777778 6.22222222222222 
        26.06315         24.84969         23.63622         22.42275         21.20929         19.99582 
6.66666666666667 7.11111111111111 7.55555555555556                8 
        18.78236         17.56889         16.35542         15.14196 

 qsec effect
qsec
            14.5 15.4333333333333 16.3666666666667             17.3 18.2333333333333 19.1666666666667 
        20.88945         20.66681         20.44417         20.22153         19.99888         19.77624 
            20.1 21.0333333333333 21.9666666666667             22.9 
        19.55360         19.33096         19.10832         18.88568 

 drat effect
drat
            2.76 3.00111111111111 3.24222222222222 3.48333333333333 3.72444444444444 3.96555555555556 
        18.94643         19.27621         19.60598         19.93576         20.26553         20.59531 
4.20666666666667 4.44777777777778 4.68888888888889             4.93 
        20.92508         21.25486         21.58464         21.91441
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because it accomplishes the goal if I am looking for a linear fit (which by my question title sounds like the only thing I'm looking for). Unfortunately that is not quite as generic as I would want it to be. This is actually for the `predict` function that is short for `predict.gam` in the `qgam` package, and so automating it through a function designed for linear effects won't solve my issue. It needs to be able to use `predict` as a basic function without a linear regression wrapper.